# How do I make Terminator gain focus on un-hiding?

Tags: gnome-shell, gnome-terminator

I have been using Terminator as a drop-down terminal, using the `hide_window` key binding. It works well, but has a glaring flaw. When the Terminator window is unhidden, it doesn't have focus. And often enough, I just press the key for Terminator, start typing immediately ... and hilarity ensues. How do I make Terminator gain focus as well?

- GNOME Shell
- Arch Linux / Ubuntu 14.04 (the behaviour is the same on both systems)
- There is only one Terminator window running at any given time.

Sometimes, unhiding-hiding-unhiding in quick succession results in Terminator having focus, but this is very cumbersome (and somewhat unreliable).

Comment: GNOME terminator, right? http://gnometerminator.blogspot.fr/

Comment: @Braiam yes. So a consensus has been reached on the tagging question?

Comment: The only consensus is that [something should be done](http://meta.unix.stackexchange.com/questions/3421/we-just-need-one-terminator-to-change-the-past-but-we-got-two?cb=1#comment5178_3428), and since nobody decided what I will go for the safest one, retag all gnome terminator as gnome terminator.

Comment: Ha, funny. I have set to focus follows pointer in XFCE and it just doesn't hide at all.

Comment: You may have already investigated this idea, but focus-stealing prevention might be relevant. Comments in this [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/805870) including mine suggest that it's important. IDK how that works in Gnome Shell though.

Comment: @Sparhawk I hadn't, thanks for the information. The last comment on that bug thread (setting focus to sloppy using `gnome-tweak-tool`) is interesting - the behaviour is much more unpredictable now - Terminator doesn't gain focus if I had previously had focus on a text entry area, and in other areas it's somewhat random.

Comment: Oops, wrong way then. Presumably you tried the other options there. The KDE nomenclature of setting `Focus stealing prevention` to `None` makes sense to me. I'm not sure if setting `Window focus mode` to `Sloppy` means focus will be stolen more or less easily.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this patch. I found it on the [bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/805870) @[Sparhawk](https://unix.stackexchange.com/users/18887/sparhawk) provided and the [user said it worked](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/805870/comments/10). I assume you know how to use the `patch` command. It also worked for me. (I have the same issue.)

[Click here for a comprehensive `patch` manual.](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/patch.1)

```
=== modified file 'terminatorlib/window.py'
--- terminatorlib/window.py 2011-08-22 20:05:38 +0000
+++ terminatorlib/window.py 2012-03-30 21:02:28 +0000
@@ -273,6 +273,12 @@
             if self.position:
                 self.move(self.position[0], self.position[1])
             self.show()
+            self.grab_focus()
+            try:
+                t = gtk.gdk.x11_get_server_time(self.window)
+            except AttributeError:
+                t = 0
+            self.window.focus(t)
         else:
             self.position = self.get_position()
             self.hidefunc()
```

With Terminator 1.90, it seems a different change has to be made. From [comment #18 on the same bug report](https://bugs.launchpad.net/terminator/+bug/805870#yui_3_10_3_1_1483861255002_1618):

> I've changed lines 307-311 to:
>
> ```
>         try:
>             from gi.repository import GdkX11
>             t = GdkX11.x11_get_server_time(self.get_window())
>         except AttributeError:
>             t = 0
>         self.get_window().focus(t)
> ```

Comment: Worked for me too.

Comment: does this work for Terminator 1.91 too?

Comment: Thanks, second patch ".. I've changed lines 307-311 to: .." worked for me. OS: Debian GNU/Linux 9.12 (stretch) Terminator: 1.90